# Changing synchronous xmlhhtprequest to asynchronous promise gives different result

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest

I was having trouble while converting a synchronous function to asynchronous.
the existing code is like below

```
$scope.getTask = function (input, id) {
                    var result = '';
                    if (condition) {
                        // Get all tasks.
                        var tasks = $scope.getAllTasks(id);
                        if (!angular.isUndefined(tasks)) {
                            var result = 'Failed';
                            for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
                                if (condition) {
                                    result = 'Success';
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (condition) {
                        result = 'Failed';
                    }
                    else {
                        if (input != null || input != '') {
                            result = input.toLowerCase();
                        }
                    }
                    return result;
                }

                $scope.getAllTasks = function (id) {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    var url = "/api/workflow/" + id;
                    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
                    xhr.send();
                    return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                }
```

But now i need to make this async , so i have tried using promises but that didnt help.
It is not resolving properly. Please find what i have tried

```
$scope.getStatus = function (input, id) {
                        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        var result = '';
                        if(condition){ 
                            getAllTasks(id).then(function(response){
                                var tasks = response.data;
                                if (!angular.isUndefined(tasks)) {
                                    var status = 'Failed';
                                    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
                                    if (condition) {
                                        result = 'Success';
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                }
                                resolve(result);
                                return result;
                            });

                            resolve(result);

                        }
                        else if (condition) {
                            result = 'Failed';
                        }
                        else {
                            if (input != null || input != '') {
                               result = input.toLowerCase();
                            }
                        }
                    resolve(result);
                            return result;
                        });
                    }


                    var getAllTasks = function (id) {
                            const url = "/api/workflow/" + id;
                             return $http({method: 'GET', url})
                                .then((response) => {
                                    return resolve(response)
                                });
                    }
```

But this is always returning [object promise].
I need to return the value as string like ' Failed' 'Success'.
Suggest what i am missing here.
I know promise will return a promise object from docs, but how to handle this.

$scope.getStatus is used in directives  to fill the columns in jquesry datatable.
Code snippet is below

```
 'sTitle': "<strong>" + $translate("list.StatusColumn") + "</strong>",
                                    'mData': function (data, type, val) {
                                        return $scope.getStatus(data.input, data.id);
                                    },
                                    'width': "16%",
                                    'defaultContent': ""
```

Comment: `But this is always returning [object promise].` yes, that's what Promises return ... a Promise - however, since you're using it correctly, `.then(function(response) {` response here will be the response, not a promise - sorry, not using it correctly ... remove `.then((response) => {
            return resolve(response)
        });` - it makes no sense, since there is no `resolve` function available in getAllTasks

Comment: @JaromandaX ok I got that point, But is there any way to get the data returned instead of promise

Comment: returned where? from getAllTasks? no, it returns a Promise (after you fix the code)

Comment: oh, you want `$scope.getStatus` to return a result not a promise ... well, you can't .. because asynchronous code can not return results synchronously

Comment: you know your code currently returns a Promise that resolves to one of `'Success'`, `'Failed'` or `''`

Comment: Ok Is there any way to change  the working code(synchronous code) to asynchronous code in that case.

Comment: yes, return a Promise, or use a callback - either way `$scope.getStatus` can not return the result synchronously - once you introduce asynchrony, there is no way to "undo" it - because of the very nature of a result that comes back "at an unpredictable point in the future"

Comment: how are you using/calling `$scope.getStatus`? That is where you'll need to make some adjustments to your code - the code that calls getStatus

Comment: that is simply returning it return $scope.getStatus(data.input, data.id);  in a directive.js to fill a column (query datatable)

Comment: so, why is the fact that `$scope.getStatus` returns a Promise a problem?

Comment: I failed to find a way to return the data reside inside the promise in getstatus method

Comment: yes, but **why do you need to** ... you just call it using `return $scope.getStatus(data.input, data.id);` ... so that's some function that is `return`ing ... so something is calling that other function, and it's expecting the result synchronously? if so, then THAT is where you need to change your code to work with `promise.then` - but as that code is *two functions removed* from the code you posted, then there's not much more to be said ... i.e. post the code *you have a problem with* - in this case, the code is the code that doesn't know what to do with a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

first,Dont handle your http request here if you are handling it in your other promise:

```
var getAllTasks = function (id) {
                            const url = "/api/workflow/" + id;
                             return $http({method: 'GET', url});   
                    }
```

second: stop returning anything from this promise's callback function as you are returning result that you are also setting in resolve and you can get it in success handler of then function like this:

```
$scope.getStatus = function (input, id) {
                        var result = '';
                        if(condition){ 
                            getAllTasks(id).then(function(response){
                                var tasks = response.data;
                                if (!angular.isUndefined(tasks)) {
                                    result = 'Failed';
                                    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
                                    if (condition) {
                                        result = 'Success';
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                }

                                return result;
                            });

                            return result;

                        }
                        else if (condition) {
                            result = 'Failed';
                        }
                        else {
                            if (input != null || input != '') {
                               result = input.toLowerCase();
                            }
                        }

                            return result;

                    }

console.log($scope.getStatus());
```

Comment: You could make this code more readable by formatting it better than the OP ... and by avoiding the implicit Promise constructor anti-pattern

Comment: Thank You @Gaurav. But i am getting an error here $scope.getStatus.then is not a function

Comment: edited my answer... try again. i forgot to call the $scope.getStatus method.

Comment: @JaromandaX Because he has written some logic before sending the result not just resolving using the response of previous that's why i am not able to see the implicit Promise constructor anti-pattern.

Comment: right - so, what you're saying is you don't understand Promises?

Comment: Not here, while your code is "better" than the OP's, for sure, the Promise constructor isn't a big deal (I can see why you would need something) - but the issue is, that what the OP **wants** is a way to make asynchronous request return a result synchronously ... an impossibility ...

Comment: I think this will work according to your need @Eddy edited the code

Comment: @GauravSingh But it is always returning empty string. I think it is not entering getAllTaks(Id). then (function)

Comment: what is "condition" in the code, check it's value in console and why are you using if(condition){}else if(condition) isn't it redundant? try running in debug mode...

Comment: @GauravSingh The if , else conditions are based on the 'input' value. Tried running in debug mode. But it is not waiting for getAllTasks(id).then(function(response). That is it is entering if condition , but not resolving getAllTasks(id).then

Comment: so check your getalltasks(id) method you must be getting some error code in console